# moment.js conversions having no effect

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have an input field where the user is required to select a date/time
The local machine will always be in either GMT or BST depending on the time of year.

For those who aren't aware of UK time shenanigans:

GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) is always equal to UTC

BST (British Summer Time) is GMT+1 during the summer months

The dates the users enter will be stored in a database that is set to GMT, thus never offsets the time. Hence I need to convert from what the user enters into GMT / UTC.

However my conversions are resulting in the same date being returned.

What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/r68owagL/

Here is the code from the jsFiddle

```
function log(obj) {
    var html = "<table>"
    for(var member in obj)
    {
        html += "<tr>"
              + "<td>" + member + ": </td>"
              + "<td>" + obj[member].format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + "</td>"
              + "</tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
}

var strDate = '2016-07-14 10:51:00';
var obj = {
  n: moment(strDate),                    //Gives: 2016-07-14 10:51:00
  u: moment.utc(strDate),                //Gives: 2016-07-14 10:51:00
  b: moment.tz(strDate, "Europe/London") //Gives: 2016-07-14 10:51:00
}

log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the format string and just output the dates like so

```
 obj[member].format()
```

then it is output like so

```
n:  2016-07-14T10:51:00+02:00
u:  2016-07-14T10:51:00+00:00
b:  2016-07-14T10:51:00+01:00
```

So the custom format string just outputs the dates without taking the offsets into account. To take them into account, convert it to UTC before printing them out like so

```
obj[member].utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

which results in

```
n:  2016-07-14 08:51:00
u:  2016-07-14 10:51:00
b:  2016-07-14 09:51:00
```

Comment: Close enough for me to the correct my code: https://jsfiddle.net/r68owagL/1/, so marking it as the answer. Basically set the date then .utc() it. Rather than .utc() then set the date - makes sense now I think about it - doing it my way was saying this is a UTC date, rather than this is a local date.

Comment: Further update, it would seem that reading the user selected value from an <input> in the UK format of dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss resulted in moment.js giving the same values post conversion again. https://jsfiddle.net/r68owagL/2/ To fix I had to manually set the format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss before passing it to moment().

Comment: @Morvael, you are getting a deprecation warning that moment construction falls back to JS date. You need to specify a format for your dates. Then you will not have to manually parse. See http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ and http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/

Comment: Thanks @MaggiePint, resolved the issue now; - https://jsfiddle.net/r68owagL/3/ - not been using moment() for long, its full of little surprises

Comment: @Morvael, if you're new to the library I recommend: http://momentjs.com/guides/ and https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/. Those two URLS cover 90% of questions I answer on Stack Overflow.